# How can I wait until a HttpServer has finished (i.e. join its background thread)?

Tags: java, multithreading, httpserver

I have this code:

```java
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

...

DatabaseConnection dbConnection = ...
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create();
server.createContext("/endpoint", new MyHandler(dbConnection));
server.start();

// What should I do here in order to wait until `server` stops?

dbConnection.close()
```

The [`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer#start` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html#start()) states: "Starts this server in a new background thread."

I would like to call `dbConnection.close()` after `server`'s background thread stops executing (which may happen e.g. because I press Ctrl+C). But the `HttpServer` documentation doesn't specify any way to access the background thread, so I can't figure out how to `.join()` it.

How can I wait until the `HttpServer`'s background thread stops? Or is there another way I can ensure that `dbConnection.close()` is called when my app shuts down?

Answer (score 1):

The server will not stop by itself. You need to tell it to stop. According to documentation, there is a `stop(int delay)` method for that.

So your question should rather be "how do I wait in my program until I tell the server to stop?"

Few options:

- Wait for user to press a key. Upside: very simple. Downside: cannot be used for background services.
- Wait for Java process to exit (use shutdown hooks); note however that this is not the best as you have limited control over the order in which shutdown hooks are being called, and JVM might be hard-killed anyway so it might not be possible to achieve what you want.
- Wait for some other external event - request on special URL, timeout, OS signal, appearance of a designated file in a designated directory etc.
- Use some kind of inter-process communication (shared memory, named pipes, sockets, streams, JMS etc.) to communicate with your program externally. This way, you can make a separate program that will connect to the socket and send "EXIT" command to your server program. When you receive the "EXIT" command in your server program, you shutdown the server, close the connection and exit the main method.

The last option is the best and the cleanest, but it requires a bit more work. It's also very versatile because you can expand the command set to include other useful stuff - reloading the server configuration file, add or remove URL mappings at runtime, get service statistics and so on. This is for example how Apache works.

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure that `dbConnection` gets closed when the Java process terminates is to add a shutdown hook:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    dbConnection.close();
}));
```

In order to use this approach, `dbConnection` must be effectively `final` so that it can be captured in the lambda.

Comment: No need to declare dbConnection as final, it being _effectively final_ should be enough

Comment: @lugiorgi I reworded to effectively final, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure that something will always close is to use a `Try with Resources`
this construct will always close whatever `Closeable` is supplied to the parenthesis when the block of code is finished executing.

Here is an example.

```
try(dbConnection) {
// do any sort of work inside this block. 
}
```

The dbConnection or Closeable will ensured to be closed this way.

Try with Resources 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I'm not sure that this works in my case. The problem is that there is no way to tell when the code is done executing, because the work happens in a background thread. So if I replace `// do any sort of work inside this block.` with `server.start()`, it will immediately exit the block once the background thread is spawned, and then the database connection will be closed, even though the server is still running.